# Circumference of convergence for the power series of $\ln(x^2+2)$

Tags: calculus, functions, power-series

a) Given $f(x)=\ln(2+x^2)$. Prove f has a power series in the neighborhood of $x=0$ and find its radius of convergence.

This is my solution:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \ln (x^2 + 2) = \ln4+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(x^2-2\right)^n}{n\cdot4^{n}}
\end{equation}

And I calculate the radius like this:

$$
L=\lim \limits_{x \to\infty} \lvert 
\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+2}\left(x^2-2\right)^{n+1}}{(n+1)\cdot4^{n+1}} \cdot\frac{n\cdot4^{n}}{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(x^2-2\right)^n}\rvert=
\lim \limits_{x \to\infty}\lvert 
\frac{-n(x^2-2)}{4(n+1)}
\rvert =|x^2-2| \lim \limits_{x \to\infty}|\frac{n}{4(n+1)}|=\frac{|x^2-2|}{4}
$$
The series converges when $L <1$, therefore it converges when:
$
|x^2-2|<4\Rightarrow|x|<\sqrt6
$

b) Decide in which points of the circumference of convergence the power series is convergent. The power series defines a function $h$ over a subset $S$ contained in the circumference of convergence. Find $S$ and study the continuity of $h$ in $S$.

When it comes to b), I'm completely lost. I have not found anything on circumferences of convergence and my professor won't give us any clue. How could I approach this? Any tips would be gladly appreciated.

**EDIT** after reading comments:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \ln (x^2 + 2) = \ln2+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{2^nn}
\end{equation}

And I get that the radius of convergence is $\sqrt2$. To find the interval of convergence I study the values x that give $L=1$.
For $
x=\sqrt2: 
$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}(\sqrt2)^{2n}}{2^nn}=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}2^{n}}{2^nn}=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}=\ln2
$$
For $x=-\sqrt2$ we get the same result. Therefore the interval of convergence is $-\sqrt2\le x\le\sqrt2$

Comment: It means that you need to check what happens with the limit is exactly $1$, which is where the ratio test is inconclusive. You know it definitely converges when the limit is smaller than $1$, and it definitely diverges when the limit is greater than $1$. But you need to say what happens when the limit is exactly $1$; that usually means checking two values of $x$.

Comment: You started with a wrong series. Since you know the series of $\ln(1+y)$ at $y=0$, try to reduce your problem to that one. Hint: $\ln(2+x^2)=\ln(2)+\ln(1+x^2/2).$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes @AnneBauval, I've already corrected them.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin is the interval I've calculated the circumference they are asking for? What is the next step I need to take?

Comment: The circumference is the edge. The "circumference of a circle" is not the disc, it's the edge. The "circumference" here is exactly what I said in my comment: the two endpoints of the interval of convergence, where the Ratio Test is inconclusive.

Comment: The interval of convergence is: the points where the Ratio Test gives al limit $L\lt 1$, plus whichever points at which the Ratio Test gives a limit of $1$ *and* the resulting series converges. You don't just check the points where the limit is $1$.

Comment: So the subset they are asking for is  $S=(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$ , the function $h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{2^nn}$ and it is continuous in S. Am I right?

Comment: Not according to your work. You claim that the series converges on both $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$, so why did you exclude them from the subset $S$? And the question is asking whether the resulting function is continuous on (all of) $S$, something you haven't addressed at all.

Comment: My fault, should have said $S=[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2]$. In class, we looked at Abel's Theorem: If $g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x)^n$ converges at $x=R>0$, then the power series converges uniformly on $[0,R]$. A similar result holds when the power series converges at $x=-R<0$. Since uniform convergence implies continuity we have the result. Does that work?